Rollup / React tsx : Error: 'createRoot' is not exported by node_modules/react-dom/client.js
I try to make a react tsx wep app, builded with rollup, but when I try to add a custom widget to my app, I have this error :
Error: 'createRoot' is not exported by node_modules/react-dom/client.js

The error occurs with this code, at the line with the "createRoot", when I execute npm rollup -c for build files inside my dist folder :
import * as React from "react";
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { ReactWidgetFactory } from "@marquito73/marquito-utils-react-lib";
import { TestReact, TestReactProps } from "../Components/TestReact/TestReact";

export default class CustomReactWidgetFactory extends ReactWidgetFactory {
    public static createTestReact(props: TestReactProps, containerId: string) {
        const _props: TestReactProps = { ...props };
        const root = createRoot(document.getElementById(containerId) as HTMLElement);
        root.render(<TestReact {..._props} />);
    }
}

This is my web app git repository, for the context, and all config files : https://github.com/marquito73/Marquito.Web.React.Template

My rollup.config.json :
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import multiInput from 'rollup-plugin-multi-input';
import replace from 'rollup-plugin-replace'
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import json from "@rollup/plugin-json";
import postcss from "rollup-plugin-postcss";
import svgr from '@svgr/rollup';
import copy from 'rollup-plugin-copy';

dotenv.config();

const getFileName = (fileName) => {
    return `./node_modules/@marquito73/marquito-utils-react-lib/dist/files/${fileName}`;
}

export default {
    input: ["src/**/*.ts"],
    output: {
        format: "es",
        dir: "../wwwroot/dist",
        sourcemap: true,
    },
    plugins: [
        replace({
            "process.env.NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify("development"),
        }),
        resolve(),
        multiInput(),
        typescript({
            tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json"
        }),
        json(),
        postcss(),
        svgr(),
        copy({
            targets: [
                {
                    src: getFileName("marquito.svg"),
                    dest: "../wwwroot/dist/fonts/",
                },
                {
                    src: getFileName("marquito.eot"),
                    dest: "../wwwroot/dist/fonts/",
                },
                {
                    src: getFileName("marquito.ttf"),
                    dest: "../wwwroot/dist/fonts/",
                },
                {
                    src: getFileName("marquito.woff"),
                    dest: "../wwwroot/dist/fonts/",
                },
            ],
        }),
    ],
};

Thank you in advance for any help !

Okay, I found the solution for my problem with this Github issue : https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/3956#issuecomment-612104302
I just add commonjs() to my rollup.config.js, and it's work now, I can use my custom component
